# How to check if a table has any duplicated rows column in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, html-table

I want to check if a table has any duplicated column in rows. If a table has, an alert to be displayed that without adding database of. Then I want to  unplug duplicated data from the table. How can I do that? I'm waiting for your help!

This is my table has duplicated class A:

[image]

This is my table html code.

```
 <table id="tblSeatInfo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Class
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Given Seat
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Adult Buying Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Adult Selling Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Child Buying Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Child Selling Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Infant Buying Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Infant Selling Price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="tr-notremove">
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="class" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control seat" type="text" name="givenseat" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="adultbuyingprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="adultprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="childbuyingprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="childprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="infantbuyingprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control decimal" type="text" name="infantprice" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success btn-addnewseat">Add</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning btn-removenewseat">Remove</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('[name="class"]').on('input',function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('[name="class"]').not(this).each(function(){
     if($(this).val() == value) {
       alert('duplicate content');
     }
  }) 
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r3oq636w/1/